# To add dynamically in an array of objects(CD)?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class CD
{

public : 
    void getCDdetails(CD *);
    void printCDD(CD *) const;
    int putCount() const
    {
    return count;
    }

private :
static int count;
char Title[60];
char Artist[60];
char Type;
int Tracks;
};


int CD :: count=0;

void CD :: getCDdetails(CD * cd)
{
cd=new CD[putCount() + 1];  //THIS LINE IS NOT HELPING
    for(int j=putCount(); j < 100; j++)
    {
    cout << "\nTitle :";
    cin >> cd[j].Title;
    cout << "\nArtist :";
    cin >> cd[j].Artist;
    cout << "\nType :";
    cin >> cd[j].Type;
    cout << "\nTracks";
    cin >> cd[j].Tracks;
    count++;
    cout << "Details added, Press enter to continue";
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    break;;
    }
    printCDD(cd);
}


void CD :: printCDD(CD * cd) const 
{

cout << "\nThere are " << putCount() << " number of CD details in the database at  present";
    for(int j=0; j < putCount(); j++)
    {
    cout << "\nTitle : " << cd[j].Title;
    cout << "\nArtist : " << cd[j].Artist;
    cout << "\nType : " << cd[j].Type;
    cout << "\nTracks " << cd[j].Tracks << endl;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    cout << "\nPress enter to continue";
    getchar();
}


void display_menu();

int main()
{
display_menu();
return 0;
}

void display_menu()
{
CD * st;
int choice;
int j;
for(;;)
{
system("clear");
cout << "\n\t\t\t\tCurrent number of CDs in the CD database is  " << st[0].putCount();
cout << "\n1:Enter a CD detail"   \
     << "\n2:Print all the CD details" \
     << "\n3:Quit"  \
     << "\nEnter your choice : ";
cin >> choice;
     switch(choice)
     {
     case 1 :
        st[0].getCDdetails(st);
            break;
     case 2 :
            st[0].printCDD(st);
            break;
     case 3 :
           exit(0);
     default :
            cout << "\nPlease enter valid choice";
            fflush(stdin);
            getchar();
            break;
     }
  }         
}
```

This line(cd=new CD[putCount() + 1];) does not helps because everytime I go for adding a data to the object array then perhaps a new chunk of memory gets allocated and the data added previously gets lost

example : when i add to the ist object its O.K

```
 Current number of CDs in the CD database is  0
  1:Enter a CD detail
  2:Print all the CD details
  3:Quit
  Enter your choice : 1
  Title :a
  Artist :a
  Type :a
  Tracks1
  Details added, Press enter to continue

There are 1 number of CD details in the database at present
Title : a
Artist : a
Type : a
Tracks 1

Press enter to continue

1:Enter a CD detail
2:Print all the CD details
3:Quit
Enter your choice : 1
Title :a
Artist :a
Type :a
Tracks1
Details added, Press enter to continue

There are 1 number of CD details in the database at present
Title : a
Artist : a
Type : a
Tracks 1

                   Press enter to continue

                     Current number of CDs in the CD database is  1
1:Enter a CD detail
2:Print all the CD details
3:Quit
Enter your choice : 1
Title :b
Artist :b
Type :b
Tracks2
Details added, Press enter to continue

There are 2 number of CD details in the database at present
**Title :
Artist :
Type :
Tracks 0**   //ITS NOT DISPLAYING THAT WAS ADDED JUST BEFORE

Title : b
Artist : b
Type : b
Tracks 2
```

Press enter to continue

If its painful to look at it can somebody show me some example how to dynamically add to an object array ( I am just trying to do with new operator first ) and I have not tried linked list if I am successful I will go ahead and use linked list also.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier for you to use a dynamic container like a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).  This way you wouldn't have to worry about dynamically allocating space for your array.  Also if this is homework you should mark it as such.

Comment: will vector accept user-defined datatype(class CD) as its datatype

Comment: Yes it's a generic container.